# How to get activated column's index in App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().autoResizeColumn(activatedColumnIndex);
```

I want to get a current `activated column index` for auto-resizing cells by the column after editing is done in the sheet. I searched on [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) website and tried some few built-in functions but there's no functions such as getting current column index.

Is it possible to get a `selected column index` in App Script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script? In order to retrieve the current activated column number, I thought that `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn()` might be able to be used.

#### Sample script:

```
const activatedColumnIndex = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().autoResizeColumn(activatedColumnIndex);
```

- In this case, when this script is run, the current activated column number is retrieved and the retrieved number is used for `autoResizeColumn`.

#### References:

- [getActiveRange() of Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange)
- [getColumn() of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getColumn())

Comment: It works smoothly, but when I try to check the index by using `Logger.log()`, it returns 1.0 no matter which cells I selected. (e.g If I selected B4 on the sheet, the log throws 1.0) I thought the output goes changing depends on the selected cells. How do I know which column is selected as the index by using `Logger.log()`?

Comment: BTW I changed your code to this `const activatedColumnIndex = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getColumn()` on my script because it throws an error; `Error Exception: Please select an active sheet first.`

Comment: @sniffingdoggo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `e.g If I selected B4 on the sheet, the log throws 1.0`, when I tested this. When I select the cell "B4" and I run the above script, `activatedColumnIndex` returns `2`. So I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @sniffingdoggo About `Error Exception: Please select an active sheet first.`, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script. I cannot confirm the error. So I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Nvm. I restarted my Google Script page then it works. The log returns different index now. Thank you for answering and your kindness.

Comment: @sniffingdoggo Thank you for replying and testing it again. From your replying, I could study the situation. I think that your replying will be useful for a lot of users. When I got the same situation, I would like to propose to reopen the Spreadsheet. Thank you, too.